# problem of integration of an algebraic equation

Tags: analysis

A real number is algebraic $\iff$ is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients .Define $A:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$A(x)=\{1 ;x$ is algebraic and $0$ otherwise

find $\int_0^1 A(x)dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since algebraic numbers $K$  are countable

so $\int _0^1A(x)dx=1.measure(K)=0$

since measure of a countable set is zero